# How to sum the array if it is larger than a given size

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8], [9]]
```

I only want to sum the numbers of the array whose length is large than 2.

This doesn't work:

```
a.sum {|sub_a| sub_a.sum if sub_a.length > 2}
```

because it resulted in:

```
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer from (pry):31:in `+'
```

Comment: This smells like a homework question. If so, "[How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/128421)" will help.

Comment: What did you try when you got that error? "[ask]" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" help explain the process for asking and determining what's wrong. These are also useful reading: "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"
"[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)"
"[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)"

Comment: @theTinMan, to be frank, this is one of refactoring practices in my Sunday activity. The original code was tedious, including basic `for` and `if`. I think it's simple to make question precise. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your condition is returning `nil` otherwise, and `sum` invokes `+` on that. You can try with a ternary operator returning 0 unless the length of the array is greater than 2:

```
p [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8], [9]].sum { |e| e.length > 2 ? e.sum : 0 }
# 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `a.select { |sub_a| sub_a.count >= 2 }.sum`

---

Don't try that. Try:

`a.select { |sub_a| sub_a.count > 2 }.flatten.sum`

Comment: Almost correct: *"I only want to sum up the number of the array whose **length is large than 2**"*

Comment: Tsk, tsk! You didn't test. Had you done so you would have seen `TypeError (Array can't be coerced into Integer)`. You need to insert `flatten.` before `sum` (while slapping your forehead). When compared to @Sebastian's answer, which creates no temporary arrays, `select -> flatten -> sum` creates two, a weakness of this approach.

Comment: If only we could sum the slaps to the forehead

Comment: Please see these links: "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
"[Why is writing an “Update” section in an SO question frowned upon?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368283/128421)". Remove the "stale" answer, rephrase the answer, explaining why this is useful and should be the selected answer. Code by itself technically is OK, but the general consensus is that an answer needs to educate also, so the OP learns why to do things a certain way. Good answers that teach tend to gather more upvotes over time.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sum` expects the result of the block to be an Integer, the result may not be nil, hence the error. Apart from @Sebastian Palma's solution you also can use [`Enumerable#inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject), which might be a bit more explicit:

```rb
a.inject(0) {|total, el| el.length > 2 ? total + el.sum : total }
```

`inject` has the advantage of being available in Ruby versions prior to 2.4. The proposed solution uses `sum` in the block though, so this solution still relies on `Enumerable#sum` being available.

Comment: You should confine your answer to the use of `inject`, which has the advantage over `sum` in that it works on versions of Ruby prior to v2.4. (@Sabastian already proposed your `ary.sum {|it| it.length > 2 ? it.sum() : 0 }`.). A few other points: 1) stylistically, parentheses are generally omitted when a method is invoked with no arguments (`sum` rather than `sum()`); 2) avoid giving variables the names of built-in methods (`sum` being particularly confusing here);...

Comment: ...`a` was defined in the question so there is no need to repeat the definition in your answer, and changing it's name from `a` to `ary` is a minor nuisance to readers who want to run your code and have already copied and pasted `a` from the question.

Comment: I prefer the `inject` method also, but because it's not as confusing with two `sum` methods needed; The use of "sum" as the accumulator and "it" as the passed element is confusing though. Be careful using variables named the same as methods because in a late-night, panic debugging session you can create bugs fixing those sort of things. "Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. Code for readability." — John Woods

Comment: Please don't add "edit" or "updated" tags when changing your response. Nor do you need to tell us you did something like that as we can see what and when it changed. These explain why: "[Should “Edit:” in edits be discouraged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255644/128421)"
"[Why is writing an “Update” section in an SO question frowned upon?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368283/128421)"